# How to resolve "must specify at least one argument for '...' parameter of variadic macro"

Tags: c++, clang, c-preprocessor

You can define a variadic macro in C++ like:

```cpp
#define FOO(x, ...) bar(x, __VA_ARGS__)
```

But calling `FOO` as `FOO(1)` results in the macro expansion `bar(1,)` which is obviously a syntactical error and won't compile.

Therefore GCC includes a GNU extension:

```cpp
#define FOO(x, ...) bar(x, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

which would expand the given example to the desired result `bar(1)`. Although `__VA_ARGS__` is a GNU extension it's support by clang too, but which emits a warning under the `-pedantic flag`:

> warning: token pasting of ',' and __VA_ARGS__ is a GNU extension [-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments].

Therefore C++20 includes a [new mechanism](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1042r1.html) to achieve the desired result in a standard compliant way:

```cpp
#define FOO(x, ...) bar(x __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
```

This will add the `,` only if the following `__VA_ARGS__` are not empty, otherwise it will omit the `,`. This new extension currently works with the GCC and clang trunks (with the `-std=c++2a` flag enabled): https://godbolt.org/z/k2nAE6.

My only problem is that clang emits a warning under `-pedantic`:

> warning: must specify at least one argument for '...' parameter of variadic macro [-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments] (GCC does not emit a warning).

But why? This only seems to make sense if someone only uses `__VA_ARGS__` and passes no arguments to the macro. But with the new extension `__VA_OPT__` I explicitly handle the case for which no argument is given.

So why would clang emit a warning in this case and how can I work around it?

Comment: Ugh, why not just standardize the extension that all major compilers already implement ??? Anyway it seems your question is just asking about a compiler defect in implementation of a new feature, so it would be more appropriate to file under clang's bug tracking system rather than here .

Comment: Is there a reason `FOO()` needs to be a variadic *macro* at all, rather than a variadic *template function*?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It'd be nice, but outside this example I'm relying on things like `__FILE__` and `__func__` and `__LINE__` to make nice error messages and such.

Comment: If you're using C++20 anyway, there is a now [`<source_location>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) so you can mostly get rid of those kinds of macros.

Answer (score 2):

This is already legal in C++20; it appears that Clang just hasn't updated their warnings yet.

The C++20 standard (from N4868) says in [[cpp.replace.general]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp.replace.general#5):

> If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an ellipsis [...] Otherwise, **there shall be at least as many arguments** in the invocation as there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the `...`). There shall exist a `)` preprocessing token that terminates the invocation.

Compare with the bolded section with the equivalent statement in C++17's [[cpp.replace]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/cpp.replace#4) (from N4659):

> If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an ellipsis [...] Otherwise, **there shall be more arguments** in the invocation than there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the `...`). There shall exist a `)` preprocessing token that terminates the invocation.

There is a similar comparison to be made between C++20's [[cpp.replace.general]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp.replace.general#15) and C++17's [[cpp.replace]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/cpp.replace#12).

That is, C++17 had a requirement for `FOO(x, ...)` to be passed at least two arguments; C++20 has weakened that to only require one. Clang's `-pedantic` doesn't seem to have caught up yet.